# Quotient space in case of Polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $V$ be a vector space of polynomials over $\mathbb{F}$ in variable $x$, and let $W$ be the subspace of polynomials of degree $\leq 4$. Find a basis of $V/W$.

The thing concerning me the most is that the vector space will be finite dimensional or not?

Comment: Does it matter if it is finite dimensional or not? Think of the basis of $V = \mathbb{F}[x]$ and which of these basis vectors span $W$,

Comment: @G.Chiusole I still didn't get, how to find basis of V/W..could you elaborate, sir

Comment: Take $V = \mathbb{F}[x]$. Then $V$ has a basis $\{1, x, x^2, x^3, \ldots \}$. Now, it turns out that $\mathbb{F}[x]_{\leq 4}$ is a subspace which has basis $\{1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4\}$ (can you see why?). Now, the rest of the basis vectors, that is $\{x^5, x^6, \ldots\}$ forms a basis for $V/W$.

Comment: @G. Chiusole Oh yes...Thanks alot